# How to install pyobjc on activepython 2.6 for snow leopard?

Tags: python, python-2.6, pyobjc, activepython

I need json, pyobjc and ideally psyco as well.

I got all but pyobjc working on active python 2.6. How do I successfully install pyobjc properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing it with easy install:

easy_install-2.6 pyobjc==2.2

That worked.

Answer (score 1):

To install pyobjc in ActivePython 2.6:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip-2.6 install --user pyobjc
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Managed to get it done a different way. Sure this way must work to.